# Does the Evangelical Lutheran church see Mormons as Christian?

Tags: soteriology, lds, denomination-survey, lutheranism

Does the Evangelical Lutheran church see Mormons as Christian?

Do they need salvation or are they Christian/saved?

Comment: I have to admit I think this is a weird question. For what it's worth, Mormons see Lutherans as Christians.

Comment: Do you mean the [ELCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Lutheran_Church_in_America)?  Or evangelical Lutheran churches generally? ([there are a lot of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Lutheran_Church))

Comment: @Eagle agreed... maybe not EVERY denomination, but many denominations.  If they completely agreed then they would be the same denomination.

Comment: @Matt According to Joseph Smith he said he was told by God all other Christian denominations were an 'abomination' so I'm not sure why LDS now claim what God said was an abomination to now not be?

Comment: "The Evangelical Lutheran Church" is too broad of a description to allow a useful answer to the question, but in general most Lutherans do not consider members of the LDS church to be Christian.

Comment: @brasshat Can you take that idea and made an answer out of it?

Comment: @Whirlwind991 What does that have to do with someone being Christian?

Comment: @Whirlwind991 I never said "LDS now claim what God said was an abomination to now not be."

Comment: @Matt Well I just don't understand how something can be an abomination to God and also be Christianity - like, isn't the purpose of Smith starting the LDS church was because no other church was correct?

Comment: @Whirlwind991 Christianity does not have to be mutually exclusive to abominations. People who are Christians (or claim to be -- however you see it) can still do abominable things or believe in abominable teachings. Essentially the LDS church does not deny the Lutherans their privilege to consider themselves Christians, even though they disagree on some core tenets of doctrine; they still agree that Christ is their Savior, because that is more or less how LDS constrain use of the word Christianity. http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/christian

Comment: @Matt Yes ok, thanks for the clarification I can understand where you come from now

Answer (score 5):

The Lutheran denomination, "The Evangelical Lutheran Church in America", which is just one of many bodies using the word "Evangelical" in its name (and it should be noted that there are denominations, mainly in Europe, which adhere to the teachings of Martin Luther which do not include that word in their name) publishes a document available for free download at [download.elca.org](http://download.elca.org) under the title ["Do Lutherans re-baptize former Mormons who are joining the congregation"](http://download.elca.org/ELCA%20Resource%20Repository/Do_Lutherans_rebaptize_former_Mormons_who_are_joining_the_congregation.pdf), in which it is noted that belief in the doctrine of the Trinity—that there is one God comprised of three independent, but inseparable and coequal persons—is considered by Lutherans to be a fundamental, essential tenet of the Christian faith, so that one cannot reject the doctrine of the Trinity and be Christian. By contrast, Mormons are said in the document not to accept the doctrine of the Trinity, as they hold that God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit, are three separate entities. On that ground (probably among others), the ELCA, in common with most other "Evangelical Lutherans", would deny that Mormons are Christian.

Answer (score 0):

If you define people as "Evangelical Lutheran" if they follow the teachings of Martin Luther, then they would probably believe that Mormons are not really Christians. Here is why:
Martin Luther was mainly the first, who translated scripture into the German language. There he clearly choose that the books he translated are the canon of books inspired by the Holy Spirit and through that absolutely correct (Sola scriptura). He said e.g. that the hieroglyphics are great books to read but do net belong to the original canon. As mormons believe in the book of mormon (which was not in the canon of Luther) they would probably say that Mormons are not real christians according to Rev 22, 19. But actually it probably depends on their set of mind. Some would some not.

Comment: Welcome! It sounds like you are rather unsure what evangelical Lutherans would say on this subject.  There's also a big difference between using a different canon and not being a Christian.  The best way to answer this question would be to quote actual evangelical Lutheran theologians who have published their opinion. [This is a Q&A site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and works a bit differently from discussion forums. I hope you'll take the [tour] and check out some of the other questions and answers we have here!

Comment: @P. Barth, "hieroglyphics" are the pictograph characters used in ancient Egyptian writings. Martin Luther rejected a set of books that the Catholic Church accepted as scripture called the "deutero-canonicals".

Comment: @Nathaniel I disagree.  I am an Evangelical Lutheran and I don't think they are either.  Jospeh Smith a false prophet.  Just as is muhammad.

Comment: I have a feeling Luther would have had a different opinion about the church and God if he had been given access to the Book of Mormon. Mormons consider Luther's life on earth integral in the preparation of the restoration of the church: https://www.lds.org/friend/1984/10/martin-luther-defender-of-justice-and-seeker-of-truth?lang=eng